I have a column like ��DATE, want to rename to DATE using withColumnRenamed but dont still same
Im Trying to change column name like that:
df.withColumnRenamed("��DATE", "DATE")
But still same
df_sales.withColumnRenamed("��DATE", "DATE")
How can i solve that ??????
Anyone can help ?
Theres some new way to do that ?

Assuming that you are having 2 dataframes as per your response
df & df_sales
trying to rename could you please try with the below code for the 2 dataframes or as per your need and check if it is working or not:
For DF dataframe:
column_index = df.columns.index("��DATE")

df = df.withColumnRenamed(df_sales.columns[column_index], "DATE")

For DF_SALES dataframe :
column_index = df_sales.columns.index("��DATE")

df_sales = df_sales.withColumnRenamed(df_sales.columns[column_index], "DATE")

